# No .htaccess on root directory but redirects infinitely

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have a website that has only a few .html files. index.html is the main page. Then I have extended this website using CodeIgniter 3. 
The old site was working on http://example.com/ and the new one was on http://example.com/ci
Everything was OK until I tried to do a magic. I decided to leave the new version in `ci` directory and using .htaccess added a redirect rule:

```
#.htaccess file on the root (/) directory
Redirect / /ci
```

It entered into an infinite loop and the page did not open. Then I deleted the line but it stills tries to redirect to `/ciciciciciciciciciccici...`.

I deleted the .htaccess on the root.

Another .htaccess that resides in the directory `/ci` has the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ci
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

If I enter `example.com/` or `example.com/ci`, the infinite redirect occurs in both circumtances.

Is there anything that I forgot to change? Could this be because of the server's late reaction?

**EDIT**

Just for testing, I changed the line in the .htaccess in /ci/ directory,

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /ci
RewriteBase /hh # which does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

it still tries to redirect to `/ci`.

**EDIT 2**

If I enter the full url, it opens the page. For example:

```
example.com/ci/contact ---> opens
example.com/index.html ---> opens

example.com/           ---> error
example.com/ci         ---> error

example.com/ci/        ---> OPENS! Strange!
```

Comment: Did you clear your cache?  Most browsers cache redirect rules.

Comment: @Devon I did. And I tried in different browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was all about caching, but on the server-side. It is working now.